# Promise and pipe jquery

Tags: jquery

```
somecode;    
this.function(param1, param2)
    .pipe(function (model) {
        if (condition) {
            do something
        };
    }).pipe(){
        do something else;
    }
```

I am just getting know to promises and now I have this code.
I need to make this part

```
this.function(param1, param2)
    .pipe(function (model) {
        if (condition) {
            do something
        };
    })
```

into a new function but I don't understand how to return a promise here...

Comment: Could you explain your problem a bit more? What's the context? What is `this`? Is it relevant that your calling a method of an object? *"I don't understand how to return a promise here"* Since `.pipe` returns a promise, you can just `return` that value from your custom function.

Comment: Just sharing a relevant(I think) js library - https://github.com/stackp/promisejs/blob/master/promise.js

Comment: this is just context to get our custom function...it is not relevant, you mean i can just write 'var newfunction = function (context, param1, param2 ) { var x = this.function(param1, param2);
    x.pipe(function (model) {
        if (condition) {
            do something
        };  return x;
    });  '

Comment: @Prasanth Promises are part of jQuery core since forever, dropping in random links is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.pipe()` is deprecated sice jQuery version 1.8, don't use it anymore.

The replacement is called `.then()`.

You don't need to return a promise, just return the (modified) `data` itself. The `Deferred` API does the rest.

```
this.function(param1, param2)  // assuming that call returns a promise object
    .then(function (data) {
        if (condition) {
            // do something *to* data
        };
        return data;
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        // do something else to data;
        return data;
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        // do something *with* data
    });
```